# How to load two forge viewer in same application (Angular Forge Viewer component)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am adding two forge viewer in same application but I am using Angular Forge Viewer component. all model loads only in one model. second viewer not working. I think the issue is Angular Forge Viewer component is using same Id.

Comment: Since we don't really have any official angular component pls advise which open source one are you using and we will see what we can do

Comment: @BryanHuang I am using ng2-adsk-forge-viewer npm library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that has to do with the same container being used with a fixed element ID rather than a named ViewChild (see [here](https://github.com/theNBS/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer/blob/master/projects/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer/src/lib/component/viewer.component.html)).

You can either modify the library to use named ViewChild or raise an issue on Github for the author to address this (Alan is very active keeping this library in good maintenance).