# How to integrate model derivative api (node.js) with angular 4?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to integrate forge derivative explorer with Angular 4 and node.js project.If it is possible then please describe its procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If your node project does all the talking with our Model Derivative service then it'd just be simple task of calling your node backend from your Angular front end (AJAX/Fetch etc, Angular comes with this feature out of the box) - then your node backend simply outputs the emits (compiled Angular ) as static assets (web pages), plenty of choices for this purpose depending on your server framework.

You might also want to go for a more symmetric (progressive/integrated) approach (that's if your stack model and design pattern permits) as you skill up with both Angular and node, explore relevant topics like SSR [here](https://github.com/rangle/angular-ssr).

And here's a few Angular samples to get your started:

- https://github.com/theNBS/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer
- [How to load two forge viewer in same application (Angular Forge Viewer component)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705180/how-to-load-two-forge-viewer-in-same-application-angular-forge-viewer-component)
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/greet-year-mouse-your-first-ioniccapacitor-cross-platform-viewer-app-angular-typescript