# Is there examples available for auto forge using angular 8 for viewer version7.*

Tags: angular, typescript, autodesk-forge, forge

I'm unable to load urn based document in the viewer.
Is there anything wrong while post job svf, this is my

```
 {
    "input": {
        "urn": "{{Urn}}",
        "compressedUrn": false
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
        {
            "type": "svf",
            "views": ["3d", "2d"]
        }]
    }
}
```

I tried to implement viewer in many ways and always end up in this error. Am I loading the document in correct way.?

> Cannot read property 'viewer' of undefined

```js
export class ForgeAutodeskComponent {
  private viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D;
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.initViewer();

  }
  private async initViewer() {
    var options = {
      env: 'AutodeskProduction',
      api: 'derivativeV2',
      getAccessToken: this.getAccessToken
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
      let htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer')
      let config3d = {

      }
      this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);
      console.log(this.viewer);
      var startedCode = this.viewer.start();
      if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
      }
      let documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2Fuei0yNC0wNS9kc3AtMS5ydnWQF0P=';
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

      function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
        var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        console.log(this.viewer);
        this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
      }

      function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
        
      }

    });
  }

  private getAccessToken(onSuccess: any) {
    const access_token = ; // Access Token
    const expires_in = 86399;
    onSuccess(access_token, expires_in);
  }
}
```

I would be needing the viewer as I would be performing some property changes on it.
 - I have placed the scripts files in index.html
 - I'm getting 0 for startedCode
 - Tried with both Unpadded Base64 and Base64

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reviewing some [projects](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/) on the Autodesk github. There is a typescript example on there. You could also follow the [learnforge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=learn-autodesk-forge) tutorial to get you started. If you have some knowledge of Angular and typescript you should be fine to adjust the tutorial's plain Javascript to fit an Angular component.

Here is some code to get you started.

Component.ts

```js
export class GenericViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  private viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D;
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.initViewer();

  }
  private async initViewer() {

    var options = {
      env: 'AutodeskProduction',
      api: 'derivativeV2', // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
      getAccessToken: null // get your 2 legged access token here instead of null (folow the turial)
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {

      let htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer')
      let config3d = {

      }

      this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);

      var startedCode = this.viewer.start();
      if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

    });
  }
}
```

Component.html

```
<div id="forgeViewer"></div>
```

Also make sure to include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

in your index.html

Good Luck !

Comment: thanks. 
I've updated my question, could you be able to point out where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Seems to be a scoping issue. It probally happends at `OnDocumentLoadSucces` it is inside initviewer and() should be outside of it. Try using `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, (x) => onDocumentLoadSuccess(x), onDocumentLoadFailure);
` To get the correct scope

Answer (score 0):

We do have a few samples and you may find them in my other answer here: [How to integrate model derivative api (node.js) with angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220288/how-to-integrate-model-derivative-api-node-js-with-angular-4)