# How can I create an autodesk forge api in angular?

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to set up the viewer in angular following the steps in the documentation but they are in js and node.js https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/

no me muestra nada en la app
este es mi app.component

````
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export const ACCESS_TOKEN = "TOKEN_HERE";
export const DOCUMENT_URN = "*****";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private viewer!: Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D;
    async ngOnInit() {
      this.initViewer();

    }
    private async initViewer() {

      var options: any = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2', // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken:(
          onGetAccessToken: (token: string, expire: number) => void
        ) => {

          fetch('******')
               .then((response) => response.json())
               .then((json) => {
                 console.log(json);
                     var authToken = json;
                     onGetAccessToken(json.access_token,
json.expires_in);
                 });


          const expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
          onGetAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, expireTimeSeconds);
        },
       };

      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {

        let htmlDiv:any = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
        let config3d = {
          extensions: [ "Autodesk.DocumentBrowser"],

          theme: "dark-theme"

        }

        this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);

        var startedCode = this.viewer.start();
        if (startedCode > 0) {
          console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
          return;
        }
        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

      });
    }
  }


```***************************************************
app.html
````

body {
          margin: 0;
      }
      #forgeViewer {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;

          background-color: #F0F8FF;
      }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "Viewer is written in JavaScript" should not be a problem since TypeScirpt is a subset of JavaScript.

You can get in the community-contributed type definitions by `npm install --save-dev @types/forge-viewer`. Please check here for details: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/typescript-definition-forge-viewer-v7-released

Unfortunately, we don't have any sample writing in Angular, but if I googled `Autodesk Forge Viewer Angular`, I can see one 3rd-party Angular wrapper showing on the top.

[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=forge+viewer+angular&oq=forge+viewer+an&aqs=edge.2.69i64j0i30l2j69i64.10090j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

and check this thread: [Is there examples available for auto forge using angular 8 for viewer version7.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394940/is-there-examples-available-for-auto-forge-using-angular-8-for-viewer-version7)